# MySQL - Remove second and more duplicates from SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

How I can remove from select instance second and more duplicates (so only first record from select instance should save, other should be remove).

I tried do it usning GROUP BY: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26fda8/2

but I don't know exacly how it's work. In this example, GROUP BY always save record with ID = 1. When I change query from: `ORDER BY id DESC` to: `ORDER BY id ASC`, it still return only first record, other are removed so I can't use GROUP BY because I can't manage GROUP BY using ORDER. Is it possible to remove always second and more duplicates (so only first record should be save)? This should be work with ORDER.

Thanks.

Comment: Which part of this problem do any of the myriad duplicate (pun intended) questions fail to address?

Comment: @Strawberry How I can select from database records without duplicates on `filter_id` column name, when I want save: only first record or only last record (using ORDER BY clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

-- Keep max id and remove remaining duplicate record

```
SELECT * from table_test where id in
(
     select max(id) FROM `table_test` GROUP BY `filter_id`
)
```

OR

-- Keep Min id and remove remaining duplicate record

```
SELECT * from table_test where id in
(
     select min(id) FROM `table_test` GROUP BY `filter_id`
)
```

Comment: This query could delete duplicates from my database. I don't want to delete duplicates, I want only create SELECT statement, which can be print results without duplicates, in way that I described above.

Comment: @PavelK, in other words, you want the SELECT that is the inverse of this DELETE

Comment: @Strawberry are you trying this query? It doesn't work fine. Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26fda8/22 - in this case, SQL return twice filter_id = 4. I want group by `filter_id` so this solution doesn't work fine.

Comment: How is NOT the inverse of NOT ?